# CoSign API: How to display the signer's title in a signature

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

How do I display the user's title in a signature field?

I've tried setting the Description and Job Title properties, but it doesn't show up in the signature, even when I include `SAPI_ENUM_DRAWING_ELEMENT_TITLE` in the signature appearance's flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `ConfIDEnum` section of the signing request. There is a value you can set called `TitleValue`